# What is the max number of monitors you can use in Remote desktop

Tags: windows, windows-10, remote-desktop

Is there a max number of monitors you can use with remote desktop (RDP) in windows?

Comment: What research did have you done?

Comment: Enough to know the question hasn't been asked before on SU.

Comment: We kinda like people to have done their homework, which means searching the internet in general. A good question shows that you've tried to answer it yourself before you've come asking, and that means that for an informational question like this it will show the research you've done, what you've found out so far, and how that doesn't yet answer your question fully.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/31983.remote-desktop-protocol-maximum-supported-resolutions.aspx

For RDP version 10 (Windows 10) the maximum per monitor resolution is 8192 x 8192, the maximum total resolution is 32766 x 32766, and the maximum number of monitors is 16.

This was found by searching [Remote Desktop Maximum Resolutio](https://www.google.com/search?q=remote%20desktop%20maximum%20resolution)n.